# Bug in NPM version - blacklist the patch version

Tags: npm, versioning, semantic-versioning

Say we publish an NPM package that ends up having a bug say it is version `1.0.056`.

is there a way to tell NPM to blacklist it, meaning if users have this in package.json:

`^1.0.05`

that it would endeavor to only install `1.0.057` or `1.0.055`?

The idea is when you patch the bug, if it doesn't impact any of the exposed API, then not much reason to make a big semver change? Or maybe on the other hand an important bugfix should call for a minor version change?

Obviously NPM doesn't encourage people to delete packages, we want immutability, but unless a user explicitly requests that version, I want NPM to avoid installing it at all costs?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927974/how-to-delete-an-npm-package-from-the-npm-registry

Answer (score 3):

[npm deprecate](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/deprecate) covers a historical version when you discover problem later:

`npm deprecate <pkg>[@<version>] <message>`

> This command will update the npm registry entry for a package, providing a deprecation warning to all who attempt to install it.

---

If it was only just published (72 hours) then there is also:

`npm unpublish [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]`

> This removes a package version from the registry, deleting its entry and removing the tarball.

- https://www.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish

Comment: thanks I wonder if there is something more extreme that can be done, but I guess this does help

Comment: I assumed you were talking about an old version, but if within 72 hours you can unpublish, updated answer accordingly.